# Jenkins behind Docker not working behind different http port

Tags: docker, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have an AWS EC2 instance with Docker installed. I am trying to reach Jenkins created with:

```
docker run -u root --rm -d -p 10000:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkinsBlueOcean jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

through `http://ip:10000`, where `ip` is the IP of the EC2 instance. I can reach the website while Jenkins is being set up. Once setup, however, the connection gets resets and I cannot reach Jenkins anymore. I can only reach Jenkins through localhost (via an SSH tunnel) via `http://localhost:10000`.

When I run

```
docker run -u root --rm -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkinsBlueOcean jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

all works like a charm through `http://ip:8080`.
Is this a reverse proxy problem?

Comment: If you are able to reach jenkins through localhost:10000 surely it must work with EC2 public IP too unless the EC2 security group or firewall is blocking the access ? security rules are all setup correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your ec2 security group which you created at time of your launch configuration and edit  tcp connection on port 10000 from all .
It will start working. Please let me know if still there is an issue.

Comment: I can reach http://ip:10000 during the setup of Jenkins, so the port is open. Once it is setup, I can no longer reach it.